# Why does rsync nest directories?

Tags: rsync

I've got this scenario: dir1 `/home/arek/`, dir2 `/mnt/home/arek/` (mounted with sshfs).

When I issue: `rsync -avz /mnt/home/arek /home/arek`, I get `/home/arek/arek` with the whole content. Some directories are OK in `/home`, some are not. There are no links (neither hard nor symbolic).

Does anybody know what is going on and how to protect myself?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`rsync(1)` is picky about the *trailing slash*. Try this:

```
rsync -avz /mnt/home/arek/ /home/arek
```

[See the man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync) for all the details.

**Update**

If one of the paths is mounted via sshfs, I suggest using `rsync(1)` differently:

```
rsync -avzP -e ssh username@remotesystem:/home/arek/ /home/arek
```

(The `-e ssh` might be redundant at this point; `rsync(1)` used to default to `rsh`!)

The `-P` asks for partial file transfers to be restarted (very helpful on network links that *might* die) *and* shows progress (which is helpful over network links, since they are frequently slower than drive-to-drive copies).

Furthermore, `rsync(1)` is *very* clever about doing hashing checks *on both endpoints* when invoked this way -- disk to CPU bandwidth is much better than disk to `ssh` to network to `ssh` to wonky filesystem driver bandwidth -- so you will be transferring much less data across the network.

Consider: if you append a *single byte* to every file, `rsync(1)` over sshfs will be forced to transfer the contents of every single file from the source to the destination. `rsync(1)` over `ssh(1)` will instead start an `rsync(1)` on the remote endpoint and do the hashing computations on *both* machines as necessary, and will probably only transfer the last 8192 bytes of every file.

Comment: yes, it works now ok, but only when I issue rsync from / directory. any lower - does not work

Comment: @tdi, hrm, are you sure you're giving absolute paths to both source and desination? I've never experienced that behavior before, and couldn't understand the implementation decisions that would make it behave that poorly.

Comment: @sarnold ofc, I give absolute paths. Maybe it is sshfs weird issue. Ill check it later with and w/o

Comment: @tdi, I updated my answer with the knowledge that one of the hosts is remote; `rsync(1)` can be used much more efficiently than pretending source and destination are local.

Comment: @sarnold, thanks, I am ofc aware of that, It was just a migration, developers needed to access old server as a direcotry. you know developers, they do not like to learn much :)

Comment: @tdi, heh, makes sense. You've got to work with what you've got.. :)

Answer (score 0):

It's copying the directory `/mnt/home/arek` into `/home/arek`, when what you want is for it to copy *the contents of* `/mnt/home/arek`. You can get this behaviour by adding a trailing slash to the source directory name: `rsync -avz /mnt/home/arek/ /home/arek`. Yes, this is a bit strange. It's documented in the `rsync` manpage, under the heading "USAGE", but it's not explained very clearly there.